# const_cast in constructor acceptable

Tags: c++, const-correctness

Is this a valid use of a const_cast ? I am using it in a constructor and it looks as follows:

```
KeyLiteObject(const char * extension, const char * swap_suffix)
        :    _extension(extension),
             _swap_suffix(swap_suffix),
             _swap_suffix_extension(swap_suffix) 
{
    const_cast<std::string*>(&_swap_suffix_extension)->append(_extension);
}
```

Yes, the strings will never change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that _swap_suffix_extension is a const std::string then why not just do this:

```
KeyLiteObject(const char * extension, const char * swap_suffix)
        :    _extension(extension),
             _swap_suffix(swap_suffix),
             _swap_suffix_extension( std::string( swap_suffix ) + std::string( extension ) ) 
{
}
```

Then you can totally avoid the const_cast ...

Comment: Just for the record, at the risk of being a bit more confusing to beginners, but being nicely more concise, you can have just one side of the string concatenation be a std::string object: `_swap_suffix_extension(std::string(swap_suffix) + _extension)`.

Comment: If I didn't have a object that was so well defined as string, would using a const_cast in the constructor body be acceptable though ?

Comment: @Tony: Yeah I know and I almost left it at that.  I just thought the above was slightly more obvious.  I guess it might be slower but it depends whether "std::string::operator + ( std::string, char* )" builds a std::string object before using the normal ( std::string, std::string ) add or not ...

Comment: BTW / another approach is to make the swap_suffix and/or extension parameters `const std::string&` - then not only can you still pass char* values and have the strings implicitly constructed, but you can concatenate them without any unintuitive code.

Comment: @Hassan:  In my opinion (and people may well disagree) you should NEVER use const_cast.  If you need to use it then there is a flaw in your design.  In fact it was only introduced to handle the cases where a library has not been written with proper const correctness.  That way you can actually get on with life rather than having to put in requests to get the library code fixed (if indeed it is even actively supported).

Comment: @Goz: I'd be shocked if any widely used std::string implementation allowed an extra temporary to be created... that's pretty expensive in the scheme of (these) things.  Definitely agree your code's more obvious though.

Comment: @Hassan: Goz is on the money... const_cast<>-ing away constness is very, very rarely needed. The `mutable` keyword addresses some of the caching cases where it might seem necessary. Arguably, const_cast<> to add `const` can be useful (e.g. a caller to a function ensuring/documenting that the called-function isn't accepting it by non-const ref), but the verbosity involved makes the practice unappealing, and (for reasons I don't agree with) some argue in favour of using `static_cast<>` in such scenarios.

Comment: Whenever possible avoid the `const_cast`, and here it is quite possible for any given type. Just create a helper function that takes the two arguments, composes the final value of the constant and use it in the initializer:

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible avoid the `const_cast`, and here it is quite possible for any given type. Just create a helper function that takes the two arguments, composes the final value of the constant and use it in the initializer:

```
// header file
struct test { 
   const type x; 
   test( type const & a, type const & b );
};
// implementation file
namespace {
   type compose( type const & arg1, type const & arg2 ) {
      // calculate the actual value here
   }
}
test::test(type const & a, type const & b) 
      : x( compose(a,b) ) 
{}
```

The cost of that is just writting a single free (`static` or in an unnamed namespace) function in the implementation file, and the result it readable if you choose a proper name for the function. In your case: `concatenate` or `concat` would be good choices.

While the use of `const_cast` in the example will not lead to undefined behavior, I would avoid it for personal reasons. Casts are cumbersome to write in C++ (compare with C or Java) for a reason: so that they will call the attention of the programmer: *something weird is going on here!* If you start sprinkling casts, then you will get used to seeing them, and they will become natural.